# Parsing json column of Pyspark dataframe that has one of the key value as None

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with two columns - id, cast. column 'cast'  has values in json array format as shown below.

[image]

Json structure for column cast for id=862

> "[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, **'profile_path'**: '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}]"

Json structure for column cast for id=8844

> "[{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'Alan Parrish', 'credit_id': '52fe44bfc3a36847f80a7c73', 'gender': 2, 'id': 2157, 'name': 'Robin Williams', 'order': 0, **'profile_path'**: None}]"

To parse column 'cast', I have below code

```
cast_schema=ArrayType(StructType([
  StructField('cast_id',IntegerType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('character',StringType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('credit_id',StringType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('gender',IntegerType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('id',IntegerType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('name',StringType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('order',IntegerType(),nullable=True),
  StructField('profile_path',StringType(),nullable=True)
]))
credits_upd.withColumn('movies_cast',from_json(col('cast'),cast_schema).getField("name").alias('movies_cast')).show()
```

It returns below output:

[image]

As shown above, for id - 8844, 'cast' column did not get parsed correctly. My guess is 'profile_path' key of the 'cast' column has value as **None** for id 8844 due to which json is not getting parsed.

I am not sure how to define schema such that it is able to parse when one of the Json key has value as **None**.

My actual file has 45k records.

Comment: Please check this and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `None` value for profile_path in `"[{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'Alan Parrish', 'credit_id': '52fe44bfc3a36847f80a7c73', 'gender': 2, 'id': 2157, 'name': 'Robin Williams', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': None}]"`

If you change `None` to `null` as follows, it will work as expected:

`"[{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'Alan Parrish', 'credit_id': '52fe44bfc3a36847f80a7c73', 'gender': 2, 'id': 2157, 'name': 'Robin Williams', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': null}]"`

Output after making this change:

```
+--------------------+----+----------------+
|                cast|  id|     movies_cast|
+--------------------+----+----------------+
|[{'cast_id': 14, ...| 862|     [Tom Hanks]|
|[{'cast_id': 1, '...|8844|[Robin Williams]|
+--------------------+----+----------------+
```

Please find the answer for your comment to address 45K records to update from `None` to `null`:

```
@udf
def update_cast(value):
    value = value.replace("'profile_path': None", "'profile_path': null")
    return value


credits_upd = credits_upd.withColumn("cast", update_cast(col("cast")))

credits_upd.withColumn('movies_cast', from_json(col('cast'), cast_schema).getField("name").alias('movies_cast')).show()
```

Comment: My file has 45k records. Could you please suggest how to replace None to null in a column storing Json array as string.

Comment: Is this a json file or just a text file?

Comment: Please find my updated answer to address your comment.